# Not able to execute make menuconfig to compile opensips

Tags: git, linux-kernel, opensips

I was trying to compile opensips 1.8. I downloaded it from the link:
git clone -b 1.8 https://github.com/OpenSIPS/opensips.git opensips_1_8

Something went wrong. I decided to recompile it.

Now when I execute the following command:

```
make menuconfig
```

It shows the following notification:

```
root@britannica:/home/gaurav/Desktop/test/opensips_1_8# make menuconfig/
make: Nothing to be done for `menuconfig/'.
```

Please, let me know how I can undo the changes made in the system when I executed `make menuconfig` command first time.

Answer (score 0):

You can clean up the entire OpenSIPS build tree with:

```
make proper
```

This should get `make menuconfig` working again.

If problems persist, make sure libncurses5-dev is installed, as `make` errors can be quite cryptic sometimes, and OpenSIPS 1.8 has been obsoleted for quite a few years now.